# Run Redis with persistent storage using docker-compose

Tags: docker, redis, persistence, docker-compose, circleci

How do I tell CircleCI and docker-compose to run Redis with persistent storage? I expected to see something like `docker run -d -p 6379:6379--name redis dockerfile/redis` in circle.yml where I can add a `-v <data-dir>:/data` to, but I only see `redis` listed under `services:` in circle.yml:

```
machine:
  services:
    - redis
  node:
    version: 6.3.0
  python:
    version: 3.5.2

# ...deployment commands follow, but no redis
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to persist data to the host, which in this case would be the CircleCI environment?

Comment: @david_i_smith you are right. I'm confused - will update question.